# Xpath - Text Contains multiple values

Tags: xml, xpath, soapui

I need an `xpath` which will return the **OutletActivityId** where the corresponding **OutletName and ActivityName have specific values**.

An image of the `xml` response is attached below.

*I have tried `xpath` queries like below but not getting it to work yet*

```
declare namespace ref='http://api.socialservices.gov.au/ebo/DataCollection/Organisation';
//ref:OutletName[contains(text(),'${#Project#u_OutletName}') and ref:ActivityName[contains(text(),'${#Project#u_ActivityName}')]/../ref:OutletActivityId
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**This is one possible XPath :** (formatted for readability)

```
declare namespace ref='http://api.socialservices.gov.au/ebo/DataCollection/Organisation'; 
//ref:OutletActivity[
    ref:OutletName[contains(.,'${#Project#u_OutletName}')] 
        and 
    ref:ActivityName[contains(.,'${#Project#u_ActivityName}')]
]/ref:OutletActivityId
```

**Brief explanation :**

- `//ref:OutletActivity` : find `OutletActivity` element, anywhere in the XML, where the following conditions are satisfied
- `ref:OutletName[contains(.,'${#Project#u_OutletName}')]` : (condition 1) has child element `OutletName` that contains text `"${#Project#u_OutletName}"`
- `ref:ActivityName[contains(.,'${#Project#u_ActivityName}')]` : (condition 2) and has child element `ActivityName` that contains text `"${#Project#u_ActivityName}"`
- `/ref:OutletActivityId` : from such `OutletActivity`, return child element `OutletActivityId`

If one `OutletActivity` can only have one `OutletName` and one `ActivityName` child elements, then the following, slightly shorter, XPath should also work :

```
//ref:OutletActivity[
    contains(ref:OutletName,'${#Project#u_OutletName}')
        and 
    contains(ref:ActivityName,'${#Project#u_ActivityName}')
]/ref:OutletActivityId
```